# ASP.NET - httpd.ini

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to make url rewrite by httpd.ini in ASP.NET 3.5.

I want to rewrite www.mydomain.com/random_name to www.mydomain.com/PageDetails.aspx?name=random_name

How do it in httpd.ini?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: What makes you think that it's possible to use httpd.ini to do URL rewrite in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your host is using Helicon ISAPI rewrite module with IIS6

If that is the case, confirm with them first, then you can use Apache mod_rewrite style rules.  For example, I think, this rule will work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ PageDetails.aspx?name=$1 [L]
```

It has been a while since I have done this so it might not be spot on.  Hopefully it will be enough to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

My server hosting uses url only rewrite by httpd.ini, not http module etc.